# Using link_to on a list element in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, link-to

I'm trying to making the final list element a clickable link to my `search_path` in rails using HAML but have been unable to make it work.
Here is what I have so far:

```
  %li
    = link_to('sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete)
  %li
    = link_to "profile", edit_user_registration_path
  %li{:style => 'background-color:#3D8599;'}
    %i.fa.fa-search
```

Everything I have tried results in the `fa-search` icon being put in the wrong place or not being clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
%li{:style => 'background-color:#3D8599;'}
  = link_to search_path do
    %i.fa.fa-search
```